# How to draw a straight line with Animation using OpenGL ES in iPhone Game app?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, line, draw

Am very new to `OpenGL ES framework` in iPhone. Am started to study about OpenGL ES in iPhone. I want to `draw a straight line with animation` in the `demo iPhone game app`. Where the user touching in the screen, i want to draw the line, to that touched direction with animation. Can any one please suggest any sample code to do that learn how the functionality is working. Please help me. I have spent 4 hours to get the solution in Google search. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial of OpenGL ES under iPhone extremely useful: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html I don't know whether it has an example what you describe but it's sure that when you finish it, you'll be able to draw a line as you want. Also, in 4 hours you can make nice progress in it :)

EDIT: for line drawing have a look at this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5353-draw-line-b-opengl.html

Comment: Thank you MrTJ. I have seen these two links already but, i dont have any basic knowledge to understand the codes written in OpenGL ES. Just now am started to study the OpenGL. That's way i posted question in StackOverFlow. Any way thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: OpenGL has an API that is much C like, and it maintains extensive set of internal state variables - these two things might be a bit unusual if you worked only with Objective C or other OO languages. However I still highly recommend you to go through the first tutorial, it explains very well the concepts and practice of programming for OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you MrTJ. I will do it now itself. Thanks for your help.